# How to convert telegram api sticker id to telegram bot api sticker id?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I got chat history and found stickers there. I want to get all stickers from my history and use it in my bot. But there is one problem: Telegram Api format of identifiers is different from a Telegram Bot Api format, e.g.:

telegram api sticker id - **280235483508769025**;

telegram bot api sticker id - **CAADAgADOQADfyesDlKEqOOd72VKAg**.

(it' s different stickers, by the way)

So, is there any way to convert Telegram Api formatted id of the sticker to the Telegram Bot Api formatted id? **280235483508769025** -> **CAADAgADOQADfyesDlKEqOOd72VKAg** ?

P.S. Telegram Api ID format - https://core.telegram.org/type/InputDocument

Telegram Bot Api id format - https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution:

1. Find or made a bot, which can reply to stickers with their id's.E.g. -https://github.com/GittiHab/Get-Sticker-ID-Bot. I use @idstickerbot
2. Send sticker by id to a bot (use telegram api client, e.g. TLSharp)
3. Get reply from the bot.